# Spring liquibase changeset file updating

Tags: java, database, spring, liquibase

I'm new to liquibase (I'm using **Spring Liquibase**)... Can someone please explain whether it's possible to have a manual db change get reflected in the changeset file of liquibase... I mean if we have a table A at the first time and then after I removed a column from it, how to get it automatically updated in the change set file...

Thanx

In other words, I'm looking for a **liquibase diff** operation in spring liquibase or **from java**

Thanx again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key concept of liquibase is that you don't make manual DB changes (or at least, only when testing) outside of the liquibase changelog. You should *add a new* changeset that reflects the change you want to be made. If you're confused about what the changeset should look like, read the docs.